# How to filter an array of objects based on another nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I'm building a chat application and have an array of `chats` which contains an array of `users`:

```
[
  {
    _id: 'chatId1',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {...}, content: 'someContent', ...},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId4', name: 'userName4'}
  },
  {
    _id: 'chatId2',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {...}, content: 'someContent', ...},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId2', name: 'userName2'}
  },
  {
    _id: 'chatId3',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {...}, content: 'someContent', ...},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId3', name: 'userName3'}
  },
]
```

And a separate array of `users`:

```
[
  {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
  {_id: 'userId2', name: 'userName2'},
  {_id: 'userId3', name: 'userName3'},
  {_id: 'userId4', name: 'userName4'}
]
```

The recurring user in `chats`, `userName1` will be the logged in user.

My `chats` array is already sorted by `updatedAt` when they are fetched from the backend so the most recent chat is at the top.

What I'm trying to do is arrange my `users` array so that they match the order that the unique user appears in the `chats` array which can be updated as messages get sent.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
const usersToSort = [];
chats.map((c) => {
  usersToSort.push(c.users.filter((u) => u._id !== userId1));
});
const sorted = [].concat.apply([], usersToSort);
```

By filtering out the logged in user and pushing the unique user's id into an empty array I can order the users the way I need to, however the problem with this is that it empties the `chats` array of the user who is receiving the message as they have a completely different array of `users` so I need to find another way of doing this.

Have been working at it for some time now and still coming up stuck.

Comment: Note that `map` returns an array. The code shown uses it like `forEach`. That code could just be `usersToSort = chats.map((c) => c.users.filter((u) => u._id !== userId1)).flat();` (the `flat()` there to flatten the array of array of users to just an array of users (as opposed to applying `concat` over `usersToSort`).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Input params.
const chats = [
  {
    _id: 'chatId1',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {}, content: 'someContent'},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId4', name: 'userName4'}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'chatId2',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {}, content: 'someContent'},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId2', name: 'userName2'}
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'chatId3',
    createdAt: 'createdDate',
    latestMessage: {_id: 'someId', sender: {}, content: 'someContent'},
    updatedAt: 'updatedDate',
    users: [
      {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
      {_id: 'userId3', name: 'userName3'}
    ]
  }
];
const users = [
  {_id: 'userId1', name: 'userName1'}, 
  {_id: 'userId2', name: 'userName2'},
  {_id: 'userId3', name: 'userName3'},
  {_id: 'userId4', name: 'userName4'}
];

// Result.
const sortedUsers = chats
  .map(v => v.users)
  .flat()
  .reduce((t, v) => [...t, ...(t.some(i => i._id === v._id) ? [] : [v])], []);
console.log(sortedUsers);
```

Comment: Answers with an explanation are more often upvoted than downvoted.